# Error in build process templates

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I get these errors in visual studio 2008 web application,

`Error  13  The tag 'Activity' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities'. Line 1 Position 30.`

and

`Error  14  Unknown build error, ''clr-namespace:TfsBuild;' mapping URI is not valid. Line 1 Position 1172.`

What is the likely issue here? Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you have NO SPACES in xaml file. And set the Build Action for xaml file as "XamlAppDef". This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was working with Workflow Manager 1.0 and I needed to include "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Workflow Manager\1.0\Microsoft.Activities.dll" as a reference to the VS project where the Xaml workflow was present.